# ValueError: shapes (56,1) and (56,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 56 (dim 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a value error when trying to run the 'train' function as follows. How do I resolve the problem with the dot product?

```
def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
        # Convert inputs list to 2d array
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = np.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

        #### Implement the forward pass here ####
        ### Forward pass ###
        # TODO: Hidden layer
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(inputs,self.weights_input_to_hidden.T)
        # signals into hidden layer
        hidden_outputs = self.sigmoid(hidden_inputs)
        # signals from hidden layer
        print(hidden_outputs)

        # TODO: Output layer
        final_inputs = np.dot(hidden_outputs,self.weights_hidden_to_output)
        # signals into final output layer
        final_outputs = final_inputs
        # signals from final output layer

        #### Implement the backward pass here ####
        ### Backward pass ###

        # TODO: Output error
        output_errors = final_outputs - targets_list
        # Output layer error is the difference between desired target and actual output.

        # TODO: Backpropagated error
        hidden_errors = np.dot(output_errors,self.weights_hidden_to_output)
        # errors propagated to the hidden layer
        hidden_grad = hidden_outputs * (1 - hidden_outputs)
        # hidden layer gradients

        # TODO: Update the weights
        self.weights_hidden_to_output += self.lr * output_errors * hidden_outputs
        # update hidden-to-output weights with gradient descent step
        self.weights_input_to_hidden += self.lr * hidden_errors * hidden_grad * inputs
        # update input-to-hidden weights with gradient descent step


<ipython-input-21-c3bea2c48af8> in train(self, inputs_list, targets_list)
     31         ### Forward pass ###
     32         # TODO: Hidden layer
---> 33         hidden_inputs = np.dot(inputs,self.weights_input_to_hidden.T)
     34         # signals into hidden layer
     35         hidden_outputs = self.sigmoid(hidden_inputs)

ValueError: shapes (56,1) and (56,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 56 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the shapes of inputs and weights_input_to_hidden. I believe you might not need the Transpose.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I managed to figure out the matrix multiplication after printing out the shapes.

Comment: I tried removing the transpose... Still showing the error

Comment: Satyaki, actually to solve it you don't need to transpose as the shape of inputs is (56,1) and shape of weights_input_to_hidden is (2,56). I basically switched the order of the matrix multiplication to weights_inputs_to_hidden x inputs instead for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

so you only had to change
hidden_inputs = np.dot(inputs,self.weights_input_to_hidden.T)
to 
hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.weights_input_to_hidden, inputs)
?